# PHP - issue with array_count_values method

Tags: php, xml, arrays

The `skuArray` is being populated with values from an XML file, using the `simplexml_load_file` method and the first `foreach` loop below:

```
$XMLproducts = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$skuArray = array();
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {
$skuArray[] = (string)$Product->sku;  // Product->sku contains the sku value obtained from the XML file
}
```

In this case, the values inserted into the `skuArray` are `(5, 7, 3, 7, 1, 5, 7)`.

After the array is populated, we then check to see if any duplicate values exist in the `skuArray` using `array_count_values` method. If so, an `if` statement executes some code.

```
$multipleSku = array_count_values($skuArray);
```

The `if` statement in this `foreach` loop is NOT executing the code, even when multiple values exist in the array (5 and 7 are in this array multiple times).

```
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {    
  if ($multipleSku[$Product->sku] > 1) {
    echo $Product->sku;
  }
}
```

The code looks to be written correctly! Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: Cast `$Product->sku` as a string before doing the comparison.

Comment: can you check the value of `$Product->sku` because you might be pointing to non-existing keys in `multipleSku` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) { 
  $sku = (string) $Product->sku;
  if ($multipleSku[$sku] > 1) {
    echo $Product->sku;
  }
}
```